# Type 'MyClass' cannot inherit from a type that is not marked with DataContractAttribute or SerializableAttribute. Consider marking the base type

Tags: c#, interface, azure-storage, datacontractserializer

I get this error message when I try to serialize an entity which derives from `TableEntity`:

> Type 'MyClass' cannot inherit from a type that is not marked with DataContractAttribute or SerializableAttribute. Consider marking the base type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableEntity' with DataContractAttribute or SerializableAttribute, or removing them from the derived type.

The error message is pretty clear about what's going wrong.

So my question is, how can I work around `DataContractAttribute` not being decorated in the `TableEntity` class?

Code:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyClass : MyOwnTableEntity 
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

I need to serialize `MyClass` as a `byte[]` and save that into the table storage.

```
public class MyClassAsByteArray : MyOwnTableEntity 
{
   public byte[] SomeByteArray { get; set; }
}
```

If anyone has a suggestion on how to serialize this as a `byte[]`, please let me know.

**[Edit]**

I decided to create my own serializable `TableEntity`:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyOwnTableEntity : ITableEntity
{
    private TableEntity te = new TableEntity();

    public MyOwnTableEntity ()
    {
    }

    public MyOwnTableEntity (string partitionKey, string rowKey)
    {
        this.PartitionKey = partitionKey;
        this.RowKey = rowKey;
    }

    public string PartitionKey { get; set; }

    public string RowKey { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset Timestamp { get; set; }

    public string ETag { get; set; }

    public virtual void ReadEntity(IDictionary<string, EntityProperty> properties, OperationContext operationContext)
    {
        te.ReadEntity(properties, operationContext);
    }

    public virtual IDictionary<string, EntityProperty> WriteEntity(OperationContext operationContext)
    {
        return te.WriteEntity(operationContext);
    }
}
```

And then I derive from this class, but it fails writing the properties of `MyClass` and `MyClassAsByteArray` to the storage table. And that's because I created a new object of `TableEntity`.

How can I forward the parameters passed to `ReadEntity` and `WriteEntity` in `MyOwnTableEntity` to `ReadEntity` and `WriteEntity` methods in the actual `TableEntity` class?

Microsoft already wrote the code, so i'd like to prevent reinventing the wheel here.

**EDIT**
See [TableEntity.cs](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/microsoft-azure-api/Services/Storage/Lib/Common/Table/TableEntity.cs)

Comment: Do you have control over the `TableEntity` class or is it code-generated?

Comment: Hi, no I don't have control over it. It's from Microsoft. See namespace: `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableEntity`.

Comment: Anyone else that can help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Went back to MSSQL and dropped Azure Table Storage as a solution. Simply because it has too many limitations.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to override it:

```
public new byte[] SomeByteArray { get; set; }
```

and then you could ignore it with the `IgnoreDataMember` attribute.

Comment: Hi, what do I have to override? And where do i apply the `IgnoreDataMember` attribute?

Comment: @Yustme, you take the line of code I provided you and place it in `MyClass`. Then you decorate that one. See, by issuing the `new` statement you're overriding what's in the base, or more specifically, **hiding.**

Comment: I tested your approach, but I got the same error message. Also, I get this warning message: "Warning 'MyClassAsByte.PostAsByte' does not hide an inherited member. The new keyword is not required."

Comment: @Yustme, the fact that it's letting you know it's not hiding means you didn't set it up right. Clearly the code you provided here **is not** the code in the application. In short, hide the member in the `TableEntity` class by creating a member with the same definition in the sub class and issue the `new` keyword. Get that right and I'm confident you'll get a different result about the serialization.

Comment: I think you are mistaken the `byte[]` not being part of the `TableEntity` class. These classes reassemble exactly the situation I have, just with less properties. Note that the `TableEntity` class isn't mine. See this link for a tutorial of Windows Azure Table: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/table-services/